# What kind of problems can occur if we set html and body overflow-x to hidden

Tags: css

If a page is never intended to be scrollable on the x axis, is there a problem with setting `html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }`? Are there any potential risks that could cause bad user experience?

I'm not trying to hide design flaws, it's more of a precaution (if a user messes up something in their code and creates a side scroll, this should prevent it).

Comment: How should we know? you've provided no details of WHAT your overflow disable is intended for or trying to prevent, and "bad user experience" is waaaaay too broad. for all you know there's someone with a fetish for horizontal scrollbars that will now no longer be able to get their jollies from your site. that's be  "bad experience".

Comment: What content beyond your control is it that you allow users to upload? You say "user messes something up", I say "HTML injection".

Comment: Oh wait, I've got the answer to your question. "A phone with a 320px wide screen." Sorry it took me so long.

Comment: a better precaution would be: check all offscreen elements, add `max-width: 100%` to `<img>` tags or objects, ensure long string of text are broken if needed (`whitespace`/`word-wrap`/`word-break`), check if any `transformed` elements cause scrollbars and finally avoid any fixed widths :)

Comment: It's for a theme for a platform. That's how I cannot control if the user decides to mess with the HTML/CSS and do something stupid, but I can prevent it as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the contained content does not overflow the body and html containers your users will know no different.

All depends on what you are trying to do.
By adding overflow-x: hidden you are essentially just removing a fall back for users to access content if for some reason it overflows your containers. As long as your content doesn't oveflow in the first place there is probably no reason to even do so unless you are intentionaly trying to hide something that is intended to overflow.